# What is the difference between these two initializations?

Tags: c++, variables, constructor, initialization

Is there a difference between how these are initialized ? Is one more favorable than the other ?

```
class Foo{
public:
    Foo();
private:
    int x_;
};

Foo::Foo() {
    this->x_ = 5;
}

Foo::Foo()
: x_(5)
{}
```

Comment: `this->x_ = 5;` is an assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **member initialisation** and is generally preferable.

```
Foo::Foo()
  : x_(5)
{}
```

More in-depth answers are here: [Why should I prefer to use member initialization list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't quite know the term for it.